# When observed object data changes, UI temporarily is empty

Tags: swift

Whenever ONE conversation row changes, all of them are updated and it becomes empty for a split second. Why?

https://gyazo.com/a81d437fd92e236389acdd211ff83ad3

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If reloading all TableView Cells is a problem for you and if you want to reload specific row(s), the code below may be helpful

```
let reloadedIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 5/*Write TableView row that will be reload*/, section: 0)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [reloadedIndexPath], with: .none)
}
```

Only **specific rows** will be reload anymore